# GoLang Slice defaults confusion in lower bound and upper bound

Tags: go, slice

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}

    s=s[0:4]
    fmt.Println(s)  // 1st

    s = s[1:4]
    fmt.Println(s) // 2nd

    s = s[:2]
    fmt.Println(s) //3rd

    s = s[1:]
    fmt.Println(s) // 4th

    s= s[:]
    fmt.Println(s)  // 5th

    s=s[0:4]
    fmt.Println(s)  // 6th 
}
```

The out put I am getting is this

```
[2 3 5 7]
[3 5 7]
[3 5]
[5]
[5]
[5 7 11 13]
```

why in 3rd out put 
only 3 5 why not 2 3

suppose if I am going thru this logic
at each time the slicing goes decreases then :
why last line has out 5 7 11 13.

if suppose the above mentioned logic is wrong then 
: why the last line has output [5 7 11 13] why not starting with 2

[Here is the link from where I am going thru](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/10)

Answer (score 3):

A slice refers to an underlying array. Re-slicing a slice has no effect on the underlying array.

The offsets in the slice expression (i.e. the 0 in `[0:4]`) refers to the start of the *slice*, not the start of the *array*. Consequently you cannot "go back" to earlier values of the array after they have been sliced out. To do that you have to keep an earlier slice value around.

Here is the progression of which part of the underlying array (denoted by square brackets) can be "seen" through the slice (denoted by curly braces):

```
initial:  [{2,  3,  5 , 7,  11, 13}]
s=s[0:4]: [{2,  3,  5 , 7}, 11, 13 ]
s=s[1:4]: [ 2, {3,  5 , 7}, 11, 13 ]
s=s[:2]:  [ 2, {3,  5}, 7,  11, 13 ]
s=s[1:]:  [ 2,  3, {5}, 7,  11, 13 ]
s=s[:]:   [ 2,  3, {5}, 7,  11, 13 ] // no-op
s=s[0:4]: [ 2,  3, {5 , 7,  11, 13}]
```

Note how the array stays the same and the left curly brace only moves to the right (if at all).

For further details see ["Go Slices: usage and internals"](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).